# compare click count on image with click count recorded in database

Tags: php, javascript

I am developing an extremely simple login system for myself, not going to publish it online.
My scenario : During registration, user chooses his username and insert desired click count(s) for login and it will be stored in database. During login, user will first key in his username, then user will be redirect to a page where user will click on an image with onclick function to count the click(s).

Problem : How can I get the "click count(s)" from login.php and then compare with the database recorded clicks in checkclick.php ? I have tried my best to find my own idea to do it for days already. However, i failed. To be honest, i am slow and weak in programming, so i hope i can get some helps here. My friends did suggest me to use AJAX, but after went through the tutorial, i don't really understand. Can anyone please help ? I will be grateful.

Thank you so much for reading and helping on my question.

```
login.php    

<?php
include("connection.php");
$username = $_SESSION["CID"];
$table1=mysql_query("select * from pic_a");
$table2=mysql_query("select * from pic_b");
$table3=mysql_query("select * from pic_c");

$tab1[0]=0;
$tab2[0]=0;
$tab3[0]=0;

$i=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($table1))
{
    $tab1[$i]= $row["pic_link"];
    $i++;
}

$i=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($table2))
{
    $tab2[$i]= $row["pic_link"];
    $i++;
}

$i=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($table3))
{
    $tab3[$i]= $row["pic_link"];
    $i++;
}


$rand1=rand(0,9);
$rand2=rand(0,9);
$rand3=rand(0,9);


?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 0;
function countClicks() {
count = count + 1;
document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = count;
}
</script>

<body>
<h1>login</h1>

    <form action = "" name = "allpass" method = "post" enctype = "multipart/form-data">

        <p style="font-size:20px">Username: <?php echo $username;?> </p>
        <p style="font-size:20px">Password:</p>
    <p><table border = 0>

    <td>
        <div STYLE=" height: 800px; width: 165px; font-size: 12px;">
    <table border="1">
         <tr id="bird" onclick="countClicks();">
            <td><img src="password\<?php echo $tab1[$rand1]; ?>" alt="" width="76" height="67"></td>
            <td>Bird</td>
         </tr>
         <tr id="car" onclick="countClicks();">
            <td><img src="password\<?php echo $tab2[$rand2]; ?>" alt="" width="76" height="67"></td>
            <td>Car</td>
         </tr>
         <tr id="computer" onclick="countClicks();">
            <td><img src="password\<?php echo $tab3[$rand3]; ?>" alt="" width="76" height="67"></td>
        </table>
        </div>
        </td>
        </table>
        <p id="clicks">0</p>
        <input type = "submit" style=" height: 25px; width: 75px" value = "Login" name = "submitbtn" />
</form></p>
</div>


</body>
</html>

checkclicks.php
<?php
    include("connection.php");


if(!isset($_GET["username"]) || !isset($_GET["clicks"]))
die("Error");
    $username = $_GET["username"];
    $jsClicks = $_GET["clicks"];
    $phpClicks = null;

$data = mysql_query("SELECT clicks FROM customerdetails WHERE customer_username='$username'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data))
{
$phpClicks = $row["clicks"];
}
    if( $phpClicks == $clicks)
    {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("success");
        location = "welcome.php";
    </script>
<?php
} else {
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("fail");
        location = "login.php";
    </script>

<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution is set a java variable equal to your php variable that you import form your data base. For example:

```
function countClicks() {
var myclicks = <?php echo $value_from_database; ?>;
count = count + 1;
if(count >= myclicks){
window.location = "success.html";
}}
```

Comment: Obviously C.k. is not looking for the strongest security with this method of authentication, but the issue with this solution is you're effectively sending the password in clear text to the client and asking the client if they entered it correctly.

Comment: Firstly I just tried getting a basic example because they said they won't be posting it online. I know java shows code; but the php wouldn't display... also they would only see the 'correct' password if they entered the right one in the first place. But I can see your point.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use JQuery to post data to database using [$post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) The code below posts the data  to PHP file to INSERT name & count

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   number = 0; 
   $("#count").click(function(){//id of image 
   ++number;
   $('#counter').val(number);
   });

  $("#submit").click(function(){
    name= $("input").val();//id of text field for name
    $.post("ClickInsert.php",
    {
      name:name,
      ClickCount:number
    },
    function(data,status){
      alert("Insert status: " + status);
    });
  });
});
```

Instead of using `mysql_` functions which are deprecated use  [**PDO**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) The code below is INSERT for new user.

```
<?php
//dependant on your setup
$host= "localhost";
$username="XXX";
$password="YYY";
$database="ZZZ";
// connect to the database  
$name = $_POST["name"];
$ClickCount = $_POST["ClickCount"];

try {  

    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);  
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
    //
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `tablename` (`id`, `Name`, `ClickCount`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?);");  
    $stmt->bindParam(1,$name);
    $stmt->bindParam(2,$ClickCount);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    echo "Welcome ". $name;
  }   
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo "Error .". $e->getMessage() ;// Remove or modify after testing 
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt',date('[Y-m-d H:i:s]'). $e->getMessage()."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);  
}  
// close the connection
$dbh = null;
?>
```

The code can be altered to SELECT user